# power absorbed in an inductor in an RL circuit during step response

Tags: power-supply, pspice

**strong text**[image]
In the following circuit , what I found was that , the current through the circuit reaches a steady state after some time .

but , then when I plotted the power through the inductor VS time in pspice , I found that the power increases , and after some time , starts to decrease .

My question is , if the current through the inductor reaches a steady value , then how come power through the inductor first increases , and then decreases ?

[image: graph of power(L1) vs time]

Comment: "My question is , if the current through the inductor reaches a steady value , then how come power through the inductor first increases , and then decreases ?"  I don't wanna nag but there is nothing like power through an inductor.  It's always current...  I have found understanding details like that can really solidify the grasp of EE...

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY You can with absolute certainty say that real power is taken to charge an inductor with energy. What you can't say (if you were an intelligent robot-meter thingy that doesn't really exist but suits my needs in this analalogy) is how that power got consumed. Instantaneous Volts*Amps is power.

Answer (score 3):

The inductor stores energy when a current passes through it. I don't want to carry around the fact that both current and energy are functions of time, so let the instantaneous energy stored be \$\small E(t)=E\$, when the instantaneous current is \$\small i(t)=i\$. Then we may write \$\small E=\frac{1}{2}Li^2\$.

Now, the current in your circuit is exponentially increasing, and given by: $$\small i=I(1-e^{-t/\tau})$$ where \$\small I\$ is the maximum current, and \$\small\tau\$ is the time constant.

Hence, the energy at time, \$\small t\$, may be written:$$\small E=\frac{1}{2}Li^2=\frac{1}{2}LI^2(1-e^{-t/\tau})^2=\frac{1}{2}LI^2(1-2e^{-t/\tau}+e^{-2t/\tau})$$
Power, \$\small P=P(t)\$, is the derivative of energy, thus: $$\small P=\frac{dE}{dt}= \frac{LI^2}{\tau}(e^{-t/\tau}-e^{-2t/\tau})$$

This is the equation of the graph of power vs time shown in your question.

Let's check a few important features of the graph against those predicted by the equation:

1. The equation gives \$\small P(0)=0\$, and \$\small P(\infty)=0\$
2. Maximum power occurs when: \$\small \frac{dP}{dt}=0\$. Performing this differentiation and ignoring the constant term gives: \$\small (-e^{-t/\tau}+2e^{-2t/\tau})=0\$, hence \$\small \frac{t}{\tau} = 0.693\$. From the circuit, \$\small \tau=\frac{L}{R}=1ms\$, so the peak power is at \$\small t=0.693ms\$
3. Given the maximum current, \$\small I=10mA\$ and inductance, \$\small L=1H\$, the value of peak power given by the equation at \$\small \frac{t}{\tau}=0.693\$ is \$\small P=25mW\$
4. When the current has reached its maximum value, the energy stored in the inductance will also have reached its maximum value (\$\small \frac{1}{2}LI^2\$), and the power transferred to the inductance will, henceforth, be zero.
5. Power and energy transfer to the inductor only takes place when the current through the inductor is changing (i.e. work needs to be done, against the back-emf, to establish a current through the inductor)

Comment: Very good indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Power has been taken from the circuit to store energy in the inductor. There is no getting away from the fact that the instantaneous voltage x instantaneous current = the instantaneous power (at that instant). This is an absolute irrefutable truth.

So, the inductor stores (or maybe accumulates if you prefer that word) an amount of energy and, this energy is proportional to the current-squared at any instant in time. The power of the signals across and entering the inductor (i.e. volts and amps) totally cause this energy to be stored.

If you differentiated the value of energy stored with respect to time you would get the power curve shown in the question.

For your RL circuit, after a while, the current eventually (and exponentially) rises to a constant value and, at this point, the energy stored becomes a fixed numerical value. Therefore, no more power is taken by the inductor - the voltage across the inductor is now at zero and the current is at some fixed value hence, power = 0.

The power curve began at zero watts with 10V and zero current and ended at at zero watts with zero volts and *some* current. It's all over now!

Power will still be taken by the resistor but this is not stored; it is emitted as heat (or maybe light if it gets really warm).

Comment: thanks a lot . I think I have understood the analogy  :)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple visual answer just plot both the current and the voltage for the inductor.  You will see the current increasing (and leveling off) as the voltage decreases.  At some interim point there will be a maximum power flow. (If you can plot the product of voltage and current values you can also see the power curve, P=VxI).

Also note that in the real world an inductor has some DC resistance (in the wire) that would truly dissipates some of the input power. If you assume a perfect inductor then all of the input power is recovered when the source is disconnected.